# sequence of columns is changing while exporting Mysql data into excel sheet

Tags: python, mysql, excel

I am trying export data in Mysql table to excel sheet,I am able to fetch data properly but the only problem is that sequence of column  which is present in Mysql table is changing while exporting that data in excel sheet.My code is

```
from pyExcelerator import *
import sys
import MySQLdb
#get data from mysql
table_name = "ravi" #change the table name to the table name from which you want to create xls
sql_select="SELECT * FROM %s"%table_name
conn1 = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',passwd='rvrj',db='ravi') #connection information(change according to your mysql server)
cu_select=conn1.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
    cu_select.execute(sql_select)
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    sys.exit("Error message")
result_set = cu_select.fetchall()
#creation of excel file starts here
wb = Workbook()
ws0 = wb.add_sheet('0')
borders = Borders()
borders.left = 1
borders.right = 1
borders.top = 1
borders.bottom = 1
borders_cell = Borders()
borders_cell.right = 1
TestNoPat = Pattern()
TestNoPat.pattern = Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN
TestNoPat.pattern_fore_colour = 0x07
Alg = Alignment()
Alg.horz = Alignment.HORZ_CENTER
Alg.vert = Alignment.VERT_CENTER
row_number=1
for row in result_set:
    i=0
    for item in row:
        val=str(row[item])
        if (row_number==1):
            style = XFStyle()
            style.borders = borders
            style.pattern = TestNoPat
            style.alignment = Alg
            ws0.write(0,i,'', style)
            ws0.write(0,i,item, style)
            style = XFStyle()
            style.borders = borders_cell
            ws0.write(row_number,i,val, style)
            print "hi........Ravi"
            i= i+1


        else:
            style = XFStyle()
            style.borders = borders_cell
            ws0.write(row_number,i,val, style)
            print "hi......"
            i=i+1
    row_number=row_number+1
wb.save('C:\\Users\\Meenaraj\\Desktop\\%s.xls'%table_name)
print "SUCCESSFUL see in the directory a %s.xls is created "%table_name
```

Comment: I believe you can fix this by replacing 'Select *' with 'Select Col1, Col2, Col3...' Simply listing the column names in the order you wish them to be in, in the select clause.

Comment: Actually I was loading excelsheet in Mysql db and again performing some operations on that Mysql table and again exporting that data to excel sheet. so while loading i want it to work for any excel file.so can you please suggest me another way which will work for any excel sheet,thank you.